# Distributed counting semaphore in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, java-8, semaphore

I am looking for a distributed semaphore implementation (with `postgres` / `zookeeper` as store) that is similar to the concept of `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` which will maintain a set of permits that will be taken using `acquire()` and released with `release()` allowing me to restrict access to some resource or synchronize some execution. The only difference is that this semaphore should allow me to do all these actions across multiple jvms.

Can someone point to me if there is any such implementation in java or any reference algorithm for implementing the same?

Comment: look at this tutorial http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/semaphores.html

Comment: I am asking about a distributed semaphore that can be used across jvms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For zookeeper you can use [apache Curator](https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/shared-semaphore.html) library that provides Shared Semaphore abstraction.

In postgres you might consider using Advisory Locks for this and implement an applicative kind of library on top of that.