# Distributed Shared Semaphore with set of leases in java

Tags: java, concurrency, amazon-dynamodb, semaphore, distributed

I am looking for a distributed shared semaphore implementation that is similar to the concept of java.util.concurrent.Semaphore which will maintain a set of permits that will be taken using acquire() and released with release() allowing me to restrict access to some resource or synchronize some execution. The only difference is that this semaphore should allow me to do all these actions across multiple jvms (distributed).

Can someone point to me if there is any such implementation in java or any reference framework which do this?

Note:
I saw this post: [Distributed counting semaphore in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59658786/distributed-counting-semaphore-in-java)
I do not want to use Zookeepers Apache curator framework for Shared Semaphore. (I'm facing many issues and race conditions using this framework).

Comment: did you think that may it's _your_ implementation that is doing things wrong, not zookepers?

Comment: We just want to avoid zookeeper, given it's faultiness in real world